# Excel Conditional formatting heat map based on multiple cell values

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

In this example I have an Excel `Worksheet A` which contains multiple data points. There are 3 additional `Worksheets (B, C & D)` which contain the results of different statistical tests as binary code (0 for "No statistical deviation" and 1 for the opposite). What I want to do, is to have some sort of a heat map, meaning a color range (e.g. yellow - orange - red) which marks the data points in `Ws A` depending on the results from the statistic tests.

I managed to use conditional formatting for one statistic test by using the following formula a the rule for the formatting:

```
= B!$A2 = 1
```

`B!` references the `Ws B` (with the results of the first statistic test), and A2 is the first cell with the results (the worksheet is a mirror of the `Ws A`, but just with 0 and 1 in it, so the location of A2 in `Ws B` is a direct reference to the data point in cell A2 in `Ws A`).

If the value in A2 of `Ws B` is 1, the background color A2 of `Ws A` is changed to yellow.

Now I want to expand this rule also for the remaining statistic tests (also mirrors of `Ws A`) and want to create the mentioned heat map as the conditional format of the corresponding cell with the data point (yellow = deviation from 1 statistical test, orange, deviation from 2 statistical tests, red = …).

In this example it is necessary to not use VBA, because the resulting file must not be a .xlsm.

I thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: You can add many conditional formats to a range, so just repeat for =C!$A2 = 2,=D!$A2=3 etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware about this option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you want the heat map on Tab A, I would add the values of =SUM(A:D!A2) - this is the correct syntax if the tabs are consecutive in your workbook) and then apply four CFs to A2 for the eventuality that =SUM(A:D!A2)>0, >1, >2, or >4. The fifth CF is the natural color of the cell. Or, rather, adjust the natural color of the cell to what you want to see if the sum = 0.

The CF Manager has a column for "Stop processing if True". This you have to checkmark. And you need to make sure to test for the highest number is done first. So, the first Condition would be =SUM(A:D!A2)>3 and stop processing, the next one =SUM(A:D!A2)>2 and stop processing etc.